# URL Shortener API Stats

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Thru Google API I am creating programatically short URLs. This works fine. On my API console I can see the stats showing, for example, the number of requests as "urlshortener.url.insert" several dozens since I started using this API last Friday. 
Now I would like to know how many clicks were done on those URLs. When going to goo.gl I can see a bunch of URLs I manually created but none of the URLs created thru the API. Is there a way to do this ? Or can it be seen in Analytics ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the URL's stats. You need to add `&projection=FULL` to your GET request to the API. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#url_analytics) for details.

Comment: Actually you can also get the stats by adding "+" at the end of the URL, example http://goo.gl/shJjpL+ But anyway to get the complete list generated by my API ?